# Moving Average Fills in Empty Data.Frame

Tags: r

I'm sure there are more elegant ways of coding in a moving average, but I'm in learning mode.  Imagine monthly closing prices for the SPX.  I've created a moving average using a for loop that fills in an empty vector.  It works.  Here is the code.

```
moving_average_new <- c()
for(i in 1:(length(spx_Close)-10)) {
        moving_average_new[i] <- sum(spx_Close[i:(i+(10-1))])/10        
        }
```

I want to be able to do the same thing, but this time I want to use a function that calls a for loop and fills in an empty data.frame.  I've been trying like crazy but I can't figure it out.  Here's where I'm at.

```
y<- as.data.frame(spx_Close)
ma_new <- data.frame()
ma_func1 <- function() {
        for (i in 1:(nrow(y) - 10)) {
                ma_new[i] <- sum(y[(i:(i+10-1)),1])/10        
        }
}
```

I don't know if I'm initializing the data.frame correctly or if my function makes no sense.  After running the function, my variable ma_new has 0 observations.  I'd like to be able to do this using only the R core programming language, not a package.

Answer (score 0):

`rollmean` from the `zoo` package can do this. Here's an example:

```
library(zoo)

rollmean(mtcars$mpg, k=10, align="left", fill=NA)

 [1] 20.37 20.05 19.59 19.04 18.42 17.59 16.82 16.86 17.66 18.42 19.89 20.26 20.17
[14] 19.96 19.77 20.65 22.34 23.47 23.27 21.81 20.39 19.74 20.33    NA    NA    NA
[27]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

In terms of your function, there are a few things to fix.

First, your function has no arguments. The function is expecting a data frame so you need an argument `y` that can pass a data frame into the function code.

Second, the calculated values need to be assigned to a row and a column in `ma_new`, rather than to just a row in an empty data frame. For example, see what happens if you just do `ma_new=data.frame(); ma_new[1] = 10`.

Third, the function needs to return the vector of moving average values.

Here's a revised version of the function:

```
ma_func1 <- function(y) {               # Added argument y
  for (i in 1:(nrow(y) - 10)) {
    ma_new[i, "MovingAvg"] <- sum(y[(i:(i+10-1)),1])/10  # Assign value to column called "MovingAvg"
  }
  ma_new      # Return the vector of moving average values
}
ma_func1(mtcars)
```

> ```
>    MovingAvg
> 1      20.37
> 2      20.05
> 3      19.59
> 4      19.04
> 5      18.42
> 6      17.59
> 7      16.82
> 8      16.86
> 9      17.66
> 10     18.42
> 11     19.89
> 12     20.26
> 13     20.17
> 14     19.96
> 15     19.77
> 16     20.65
> 17     22.34
> 18     23.47
> 19     23.27
> 20     21.81
> 21     20.39
> 22     19.74
> ```

Comment: Sorry.  I should have noted before that I'm trying to do it using the core R programming language, not any packages.  It's a learning exercise--trying to do in data.frames and functions what I was able to do in with for loops and vectors.